# How do i tell EclipseLink to stop ServerSession Connection Queries

Tags: spring, session, jpa, eclipselink, connection-pooling

When looking at my stack trace log, i have noticed that whenever i run any queries using the entity manager or EL (JPA 2.0) provided methods `em.find(), findAll() ...`, there is an Injected bean from all related entites that trigger `n queries` depending on the relationship. I have succesfully enabled weaving with tomcat using the spring.instruments jar and i am very sure that weaving is happening and my @OneToOne, @ManyToOne lazy settings are being set and woven in time. The problem might be how i query and the `ServerSession` connection that executes multiple queries.

The stack trace that shows this :

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-04 22:26:20.959--ServerSession(1528617164)--Connection(1657707912)--Thread(Thread[tomcat-http--9,5,main])--SELECT personID, TYPE, DATEADDED, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, ACTIVE, BIRTHDAY, EMAILADDRESS, ETHNICITY, GENDER, HISPANIC, IMAGEPATH, MARITAL, NATIVELANGUAGE, PRIMARYTELEPHONE, RELIGIOUSAFFILIATION, SECONDARYTELEPHONE, version, addressID, schoolID, MAJOR, studentId FROM PERSON WHERE (personID = ?)
    bind => [101]
2012-07-04 22:26:20,963 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Administrator': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person.entityManager
2012-07-04 22:26:20,964 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
2012-07-04 22:26:20,964 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Administrator': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person.entityManager
2012-07-04 22:26:20,965 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-04 22:26:20.966--ServerSession(1528617164)--Connection(264950364)--Thread(Thread[tomcat-http--9,5,main])--SELECT addressID, CITY, COUNTRY, STATE_US, STREETADDRESS, STREETADDRESS2, version, ZIPCODE FROM ADDRESS WHERE (addressID = ?)
    bind => [3]
2012-07-04 22:26:20,970 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Address': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Address.entityManager
2012-07-04 22:26:20,971 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-04 22:26:20.972--ServerSession(1528617164)--Connection(255059556)--Thread(Thread[tomcat-http--9,5,main])--SELECT personID, TYPE, DATEADDED, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, ACTIVE, BIRTHDAY, EMAILADDRESS, ETHNICITY, GENDER, HISPANIC, IMAGEPATH, MARITAL, NATIVELANGUAGE, PRIMARYTELEPHONE, RELIGIOUSAFFILIATION, SECONDARYTELEPHONE, version, addressID, schoolID, MAJOR, studentId FROM PERSON WHERE (addressID = ?)
    bind => [3]
2012-07-04 22:26:20,975 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Student': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person.entityManager
2012-07-04 22:26:20,976 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
2012-07-04 22:26:20,976 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Student': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person.entityManager
2012-07-04 22:26:20,977 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-04 22:26:20.98--ServerSession(1528617164)--Connection(2062869828)--Thread(Thread[tomcat-http--9,5,main])--SELECT schoolID, ACTIVE, ADMISSIONSEMAILADDRESS, ADMISSIONSPHONE, CODE, description, HELPGENERALEMAILADDRESS, NAME, PRIMARYPHONE, version, addressID FROM SCHOOL WHERE (schoolID = ?)
    bind => [3]
2012-07-04 22:26:20,982 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.School': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.School.entityManager
2012-07-04 22:26:20,982 [tomcat-http--9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-04 22:26:20.983--ServerSession(1528617164)--Connection(140234280)--Thread(Thread[tomcat-http--9,5,main])--SELECT id, ACTIVE, CODE, DESCRIPTION, NAME, version, SCHOOLDEPARTMENT_schoolID FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE (SCHOOLDEPARTMENT_schoolID = ?)
    bind => [3]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-07-04 22:26:20.986--ServerSession(1528617164)--Connection(1812702959)--Thread(Thread[tomcat-http--9,5,main])--SELECT personID, TYPE, DATEADDED, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, ACTIVE, BIRTHDAY, EMAILADDRESS, ETHNICITY, GENDER, HISPANIC, IMAGEPATH, MARITAL, NATIVELANGUAGE, PRIMARYTELEPHONE, RELIGIOUSAFFILIATION, SECONDARYTELEPHONE, version, addressID, schoolID, MAJOR, studentId FROM PERSON WHERE (schoolID = ?)
    bind => [3]
```

How to ignore cache and return right away after executing a query on an entity manager object?

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord(identifierColumn = "addressID")
public class Address {


    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "ADDRESS_TABLE_GEN", table = "ADDRESS_SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "ADDR_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ADDRESS_TABLE_GEN")
    @Column(name = "addressID")
    private Long id;

    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.JOIN)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
```

Applicant entity

```
public class Applicant extends Person {

    private String major;

    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.JOIN)
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ApplicantSchool.class, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST, javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy = "applicant", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ApplicantSchool> schools = new HashSet<ApplicantSchool>();

}
```

Stack Trace; Reverting a particular OneToOne mapping

```
[TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader@747917a] error aspect 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect' woven into 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Registration_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord' must be defined to the weaver (placed on the aspectpath, or defined in an aop.xml file if using LTW).
[TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader@747917a] error aspect 'org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl' woven into 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Registration_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord' must be defined to the weaver (placed on the aspectpath, or defined in an aop.xml file if using LTW).
2012-07-06 17:08:34,910 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Found injected element on class [org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Registration]: PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Registration.entityManager
2012-07-06 17:08:34,910 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Registration': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Registration.entityManager
2012-07-06 17:08:34,911 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
2012-07-06 17:08:34,914 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor#0'
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2012-07-06 17:08:34.968--ServerSession(1433743869)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-1,5,main])--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [person] for the entity class [class org.bixin.dugsi.domain.UserAccount] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

This is the field EL is referring to

```
   @OneToOne(targetEntity = Person.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn
    private Person person;
```

Comment: Please provide more information, such as how you are querying for Person, and how Address is mapped to it.  My guess is a M:1 with address having a 1:M.  Check your spring config and the entities themselves to see if anything might be triggering the relationships assuming they have been marked lazy.

Comment: updated to show the entities that might be causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying FetchType.EAGER in both the relationships you've shown, so they must always be fetched when building the source objects.  As mentioned, the problem seems to be reading in Person (or Applicant) which causes Address to be fetched.  Chances are that the 'address' ManyToOne in Person is also marked eager.  This causes Addresses to be built, and because you have a 1:M from Address->Applicant, this query must go to the database to make sure that it fetched all Applicants.

This same senario happens on all the referenced eagerly fetched entities, and is why it is a bad idea to have everything marked eager unless it is neccessary, especially OneToMany and ManyToMany relationships.  I'd recommend you change them to lazy and only fetch them as required when the relationship is accessed, or use fetch join in queries or query hints to prefetch particular relationships that will be needed.

Comment: After making all the changes (eager to lazy) and using the tomcat loadtime weaver as well as disabling <eclipselink.weaving> = 'static' and using loadtime weaver inside of applicationContext.xml, i am able to get it running but loadtime weaving now does alot of redeploying and start up time is ridiculous. I still get an EL MetaData error on one of the OneToOne settings. Updated to show the stack trace error?